# Understanding LinkedLists References

Tags: javascript, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've been struggling to understand linked lists, and have read so many (tutorials/articles etc) about them, but cant quite grasp it. I am trying to solve a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/) here. Here is the problem statement:

> Given the head of a sorted linked list, delete all duplicates such that each element appears only once. Return the linked list sorted as well.

In the particular sample solution below, is `var current` just a reference to the node/nodes in head?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */

var deleteDuplicates = function(head) {
    var current = head;
    
    while(current) {
        if(current.next !== null && current.val == current.next.val) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
        } else {
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    
    return head;
};
```

So the changes made in the loop are actually modifying the nodes in head?

I was struggling with the thought that current equaled head, then changes were made to current in the loop, and then couldn't understand how head is being returned having been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning, the `current` and `head` points to the same pointer of the linked list. Once the current is moving by either `current = current.next` or `current.next = current.next.next`, the `current` and `head` will not point to the same linked list node anymore. Here I am trying show the steps of this process by using a simple example:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I hope this figures will help you understand how `head` and `current` play a different role here.