# Why does this code not return a reverse Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

```
Input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    def reverseList(self, head):
    prev = None
    while head:
        cur = head
        cur.next = prev
        head = head.next
        prev = cur

    return prev
```

I do not understand why the result above returns

```
Output = [1]
```

`cur` is temporary variable and not affected by changes of the head variable (that is what I thought)

```
    def reverseList(self, head):
    prev = None
    while head:
        cur = head
        head = head.next
        cur.next = prev
        prev = cur

    return prev
```

returns the correct result, and I do not understand why. It suggests that changes to `head` also change the `cur` variable, although it is changed AFTER cur is set to `cur = head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your example linked list:

> [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5]

Initially `head` is pointing to `[1]` and `prev` is pointing to `None`. Now let's execute your first code line by line. You first set `cur` to `head` (e.g., `cur` is now pointing to `[1]`), meaning from now on both `head` and `cur` is pointing to `[1]`. Now, when you set `cur.next = prev` you are actually setting `[1].next = None`. So, the link between `[1]` and `[2]` is already broken and you loose all the other parts of the linked-list (e.g., `[2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5]`) at this point. Now when you do `head = head.next`, this means you are doing `[1] = [1].next`, where previously you set `[1].next = None`. In the next run, the `while loop` will terminate because the head become `None`.

I would highly suggest you to do this type of simulation using pen and paper for the second code and you will understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed explanation! But there is still one thing that bothers me. I get that by setting `cur.next = prev` that `head.next` is also pointing to `None`. But when we set `head = head.next` first, which gets `[2]`, why is `cur.next` not `[1]`?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by "why is `cur.next` not `[1]`?"

Comment: well, let me ask differently: `head`  and `cur` are at `[1]` in the beginning. The next node is `[2]`, so `head.next` = `[2]`. At this state, when `head = [2]` is `cur = [1]` or `cur = [2]`? If it is still `[1]`, then why do changes to `head` not affect `cur`, but changing `cur` or especially `cur.next=prev` affect `head`?

Comment: (i) `when head = [2] is cur = [1] or cur = [2]?` Ans: cur = [1]. (ii) `If it is still [1], then why do changes to head not affect cur, but changing cur or especially cur.next=prev affect head?` Ans: head and cur is related each other through [1]. When you set `cur.next = None`, you are actually setting `[1].next = None`. At this point, head is also pointing to `[1]`, right? Then when you call `head = head.next`, you are actually doing `head = [1].next`, and you know `[1].next` is already set to `None`. Feel free to ask questions until you properly understand what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time with me here :D So basically, setting `cur` = `head` means that both are on the same linked list, they act like pointers. When setting `cur =  cur.next` or `head = head.next` we are moving these pointers, independent from each other. But when we set `cur.next = something` or `head.next = something` we are changing the linked list, because we change the next element of either `cur` or `head` on the list and thus both `cur` and `head` are  now pointers on a different, the "new" linked list?

Comment: It might be a good idea to visualize it by checking an example, please consider checking my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016981/understanding-linkedlists-references).

Comment: I think I got a very good idea now, and will keep practicing until I fully grasp it. Thank you so much for your help!